# tips on how to make a fullscreen div scroll on ruby rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, smooth-scrolling

hi I'm really new to programming and stuff and just started learning ruby rails.

I know there are a lot of QnA about div scrolling using jquery- I just can't seem to apply it on my code.

(you can see the code here)
https://ide.c9.io/grimandme/gifhub_0915

I think I'm making a basic mistake? But i have no idea. 
Could someone please help?

///
Additionally
I have already tried 
http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/category/jquery/

but it's a bit out of my reach because I have no idea 
how to translate that to ruby rails..?

Any tip would help- I'm really new to all this so sorry if the question is too easy

---

I realised that my question is too vague/

the jquery code i was using is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('.tile a').click(function(event) {
var id = $(this).attr("href");

 $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target}, 10000);
 event.preventDefault();
 });
 });
 </script>
```

css code

```
body,html {
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}


.tile {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.tile div {
padding-top: 70px;
}

#up {
 background-color: #222;
 }
```

and my .erb code

```
<%## scroll up page ##%>
<div class='tile' id='up'>
<%## search bar ##%>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
          </span>
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->


<div class=but_down style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red;"> 
<a href="#down"> down </a> 
</div>
</div>
<%## scroll down page ##%>
 <div class='tile' id='down'>
 <h1> yeah </h1>
 </div>
```

basically this is how i want my code to work -
i want a fullscreen div scrolling/
and when i click 'down' i want it to scroll down to my next fullscreen div

My code works - but it doesn't 'scroll' down ? and I'm not sure why.

Could anyone help?

Comment: You might need to re-write your question.  First, you posted your cloud9 account, but that's all of your code, so your question should relate to specifically what you are trying to do.  Second, the examples on alvarotrigo are quite good, so what exactly is the problem?  Third, is this a standard view you want to scroll inside of or a layout view, or a mixture?  There really just isn't enough information to see what the problem is, where you're having trouble and how to help

Comment: thanks for the reply.

Comment: @trh I'v edited the question hope it's more understandable now